# Git merge changes between two specific commits from another branch

Tags: git

I have versions from A to E. Two branch heads, Branch1 and Branch2.

```
E <- Branch2
|
D
|
C
|
B
|
A <- Branch1
```

Now I want to apply the difference between say C and D, to Branch1, such that the difference between A and A1, is exactly the same between C and D.

```
E <- Branch2
|
D
|
C
|
B A1 <- Branch1
| /
A
```

Two questions.

1. How do I do this? Do I make a patch file? Or is there a way to make this work in Git so that Git knows it's the same difference?
2. Actually I did try `git diff C D > patch.diff` to make a patch and
   then `git apply patch.diff` to apply and somehow I don't see the
   difference in it.

Comment: Can't you just cherry-pick D onto Branch1?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth We literally came to this conclusion at the same time, good on you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just cherry-pick commit `D` from Branch2 onto your Branch1:

```
git checkout Branch1
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 for commit D>
```

The reason this should work is that commit `D` is essentially represents a diff between commits `C` and `D`.  You wish to apply this change set on a different commit, in this case commit `A` on Branch1.